# Google Play Services Fused Location Provider stopped working in rev. 24

Tags: android, google-play-services

Until now I have used Google Play Services, which version I cannot say bu as of may 2015 it was about 6 months old. I have used it in the following way in my application class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if ( isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() ) {
        mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

protected synchronized GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
```

And I have accessed location like this

```
return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

This worked. Without GPS enabled on device it returned location accurate to less than 100 meters. Which was good enough for my purposes.

A few days ago I have upgraded Google Play Services library to revision 24., the result is that
`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)` now consistently returns null, thus breaking my application.

How to fix this?
I would hate to force the user to turn on GPS, because GPS can take up to 10 minutes to get a fix. Besides, my app should work inside buildings so WiFi and cell tower based location is better. But this has stopped working.
Do I revert to older version? Which was the last working version?
Is there some undocumented (as most of android) breaking change and  is there a workaround we have to pull out of thin air?

Comment: Watch your language, f470071. Some people might be offended by using such words. It will get you down-votes instead of answers. bummi already edited your question, so thanks to him.

Comment: It certainly seems that there was a bug introduced.  That being said, the `getLastLocation()` method is known to return null quite frequently regardless of the version used.  Your best bet would be to register a listener until you get a location fix, which would work even with GPS off and Location Mode set to "Battery Saving" mode.